# SQL merge results from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables but want to join them/merge them in the following way.

Table-1: (1000 rows)

ID,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

Table-2: (100 rows)

ID,col2,col3,col4

Out of the 100 rows of Table-2, 90 of them have matching ID between Table-1 and Table-2. The IDs are unique in both tables. Table-2 is usually much smaller - in some cases, we expect Table-1 to have millions of rows while Table-2 will be in 100-1000's of rows.

My desired result is:

Result: (1010 rows - 990 rows in Table-1 + 90 common + 10 rows in Table-2)
ID,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

a) When there is a match, I want col2, col3 and col4 from Table-2 and col1 and col5 from Table-1.

b) When there is a row in Table-1 but not in Table-2, I want the entire row from Table-1.

c) When there is a row in Table-2 but not in Table-1, I want the entire row from Table-2, but col1, col5 are set to null.

Is there a simple SQL query to accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to let us know the table name and column names of both tables? [ u dont need to use actual column names]

Comment: FULL JOIN  ON ID + COALESCE all the columns (except col5)